# Eclipse: gdbserver doesn't find source files

Tags: c, eclipse, shared-libraries, gdbserver

I'm debugging a C project in eclipse CodeSourcery IDE. The project runs in a linux-arm device so I cross-compile and debug it with gdbserver. My project consist of a main program and some shared libraries, which i compile with -g3 tags (tried -g also). Everything builds correctly: the linker finds all dependencies, i copy the compiled files into the remote machine and i run

```
$gdbserver :2159 Test &
```

and i can start debugging remotely after configuring IDE's Debugger. 
I debug correctly until i 'step into' a library function. I get an output message

```
[New Thread 1032]
```

No error gets prompted, except that i can't debug inside the function, but the function executes correctly and I can continue on my main program. Later on, inside another library i get a segmentation fault.

I am supposing gdbserver search for sources on my local machine as i can debug my main program. Why can't I debug my libraries's source code?

Thanks

Comment: So all the libraries are compiled with `-O0`and `-g3`?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

[How to runtime debug shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801423/how-to-runtime-debug-shared-libraries)

Looking at that question you can see that gdb can assign break points to functions inside of libraries just by using a function name.

```
(gdb) b func
Function "func" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (func) pending.
```

Comment: Not exactly my problem. How can I do this when gdbserver doesn't find the library's source files?